# What is the property of co-primes that allows CRT to work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have been reading about the Chinese Remainder Theorem and I have the following question:

Basically the CRT says that there is a $1$ to $1$ correspondance between a number $N \in [0, m\cdot n)$ and pairs $(a,b)\space s.t\space 0 \le a \lt m  \space \And \space  0 \le b \lt n $   and $\gcd(m,n) = 1$

I have checked with numbers that are not relatively prime and indeed there is no $1$ to $1$ correspondence e.g. if $m = 2$ and $n = 4$ so $gcd(2,4) = 2$ and $m\cdot n = 8$
we have:
$3 \equiv [1,3] \mod [2,4]$
$7 \equiv [1,3] \mod [2,4]$

What I am interested in is, what exactly is the property that guarantees the $1-1$ correspondence in the case of co-prime $m,n$? Or conversely how exactly using non coprime modulo messes up the CRT?

Comment: It is incorrect to say for non-relatively prime $m$ and $n$ that "indeed there is no 1 to 1 correspondence".  When $m = 2$ and $n = 4$, the two sets $[0,8)$ and $\{(a,b) : 0 \leq a < 2, 0 \leq b < 7\}$ both have size $8$ and thus there is clearly *some* $1$ to $1$ correspondence. The point of CRT is that it says a *specific* mapping (sending $N \bmod mn$ to $(N \bmod m, N \bmod n)$) is a $1$ to $1$ correspondence.  Have you looked at a proof of CRT to locate a step where relative primality of $m$ and $n$ is used?

Comment: @KCd: I am not sure what you mean by some 1-1 correspondence. For my example with $m =2$ and $n = 4$ we have $0$ and $4$ share $[0,0]$, $1$ and $5$ share $[1,1]$, $2$ and $6$ share $[0,2]$ and I already mentioned $3$ and $7$. Only $1$ is mapped to $[1,1]$. But for coprime moduli, each number is associated to one and only one such $[a,b]$

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of ideals of rings?  If so, there is a nice generalization of the CRT in those terms.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I have a general idea of rings. Do you have some relevant reference to check?

Comment: @Jim *any* two sets of size $8$ have a $1$ to $1$ correspondence between them.  Your response to my comment exactly illustrates my point that CRT is about a *specific* mapping being a $1$ to $1$ correspondence when $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Its failure when $\gcd(m,n) > 1$ does *not* mean (as you wrote) that "there is no $1$ to $1$ correspondence".  If $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_8\}$ and $B = \{b_1, \ldots, b_8\}$ have size $8$ then an example of a $1$ to $1$ corr. from $A$ to $B$ is $a_j \mapsto b_j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, 8$.  CRT is not about that or other totally random $1$ to $1$ correspondences.

Comment: @KCd: I mean unique 1-1 mapping. I don't know if there is a better term for this, perhaps my terminology is confusing

Comment: There is not a unique 1-1 mapping, strictly speaking: for positive integers $m$ and $n$, there are $mn$ integers in $[0,mn)$ and there are $mn$ integers in $[0,m) \times [0,n)$, so there are $(mn)!$ different 1-1 mappings between those sets.  What CRT is about is a *very specific* mapping between those sets being 1-1 if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ (and that very specific mapping is not 1-1 if $\gcd(m,n) > 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically CRT is simply the observations that:

- LCM of moduli is the length where all  cycles repeat again from the start in sync.
- GCD being 1, implies LCM is the same as the product.
- if $y=mx+b=nz+a$ has a solution, it is before $z=m$ or $x=n$
- This solution is unique, up to translation.

Comment: Some parts are highly abstract to me e.g. the first bullet or the meaning of "up to translation". Would it be possible to add some concrete details?

Comment: First bullet simply is a way of the third to an extent. Translating comes through geometry and plotting $y=mx+b\iff y \equiv b\pmod m$

Comment: `First bullet simply is a way of the third to an extent` that's the thing, I am not sure what this sentence means. I think due to your background it is trivial to you, but I can't really follow the meaning without a concrete example

Comment: Assume you solve the equality what can both sides change by ( must be divisible by $n$ and $m$) such that they stay equal.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't really understand it fully. E.g.: "..all cycles repeat again from the start in sync", "...it is before =..." I can't really understand the sentences. If you have the time, I would be grateful if you added some concrete example to get your statements

Comment: Plot two y=mx+b with all values integer . Find out when you can draw a horizontal line between them at integer points.

Comment: I did for $y=2x + 1$ and $y=4x + 2$ which is: https://imgur.com/a/16bODh4 but I can draw horizontal lines i.e. parallel to $x$ on all points of the vertical $y$. I don't understand the point or the statements. Would it be possible to rephrase or give something concrete?

Comment: Okay two that could equal each other at integer $x$ but anyways let's say $3x+2$ and $7x+5$,  $x=1$ for the first is $x=0$ for the second, $x=8$ for the first is $x=3$ for the second, $x=15$ for the first is $x=6$ for the second. See the pattern ?

Comment: No, I honestly can't follow the answer, your thought process or your responses. They are too succinct and abstract. Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: Each side needs change by the LCM

Comment: The only thing I see is that one $3x + 2$ has to increase by $7$ and $7x + 5$ has to increase by $3$ to get the points you are talking about. Anyway thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128836/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-jim).